# how to get the specific error when TCPServer.open fail in ruby

Tags: ruby

I try to use rescue, but the error that i get is unclear, 
and is same error in different cases (e.g in  illegal port and already used port.)

```
require 'socket'

begin 
    server = TCPServer.open(33)
rescue => ex
    puts "An error of type #{ex.class} happened, message is #{ex.message}"
end
```

and I get 
=> An error of type TypeError happened, message is no implicit conversion of nil into String

Comment: Which ruby version are you using?

Comment: You will get different errors depending on the circumstances. I can think of a bunch of things that can go wrong here: No privilege to create port, port already in use, port held open by dead process or connection because `SO_REUSEADDR` wasn't set, out of file-handles, etc. You may have to really abuse this code to discover all of them.

Comment: ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

The printed message is correct as "no implicit conversion of nil into String" is a type error.

Though the reason behind this error being raised could be this bug: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10203

As far as I can tell, in the first 2 attempts it would work without any errors opening the socket port, and binding it to the IPv4 / IPv6 address automatically. In the third attempt, it trips and expects an explicit IP to be provided as the first param (like `TCPServer.open(<string_IP>, <int_port>)`). This is probably where it fails for you as it doesn't find an IP string, and raises a TypeError.

Though this error is essentially in ruby v2.1.x, so later / prior versions don't seem to have this problem (or at least I couldn't repro it locally except for this version)